# Enable metrics for bitnami/redis with prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, redis, prometheus, grafana

I have already setup `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` in my cluster using helm.

I need to also deploy a redis cluster in the same cluster.

How can provide option so that metric of this redis cluster go to prometheus and to be fed to grafana?

On [github page](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis) some options are listed.

Will it work with below configuration?

```
$ helm install my-release \
  --set metrics.enabled=true\
    bitnami/redis
```

Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that you asking this question in the first place means the redis metrics didn't show up in the prometheus for you.

Setting up prometheus using "*prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack*" helm chart could be very different for you than me as it has a lot of configurables.

As the helm chart comes with "prometheus operator", we have used PodMonitor and/or ServiceMonitor CRD's as they provide far more configuration options. Here's some docs around that:
https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#include-servicemonitors

So basically, deploy prometheus with `"prometheus.prometheusSpec.serviceMonitorSelector.matchLabels"` with a label value of your choice

```
serviceMonitorSelector:
  matchLabels:
    monitoring-platform: core-prometheus
```

and thereafter deploy redis with `"metrics.enabled=true", "metrics.serviceMonitor.enabled=true" & "metrics.serviceMonitor.selector"` set to value similar to the label defined in prometheus serviceMonitorSelector (`monitoring-platform: core-prometheus` in this case). Something like this:

```
metrics:
  enabled: true
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    selector:
      monitoring-platform: core-prometheus
```

This setup works for us.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27iKC.png)

Comment: Did this work for you? If yes, please do mark it as an answer so that it is helpful to others.